# How to attach alert message in res.writehead in http node.js with res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "/path/within/site" })?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, http

```
      res.writeHead(301,  "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
      "<html lang='en' dir='ltr'>" +
      "<head>" +
         "<met charset='utf-8'>" +
          "<title>Hola Mundo</title>" +
        "</head>" +
       "<body>" +
         "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('DOne')</script>" +
     "</body>" +  "</html>", { "Location": "http://localhost:8086/uploadform" });
```

It is not showing alert message and directly redirecting to the given link, I want alert message first then redirect to given link.

Comment: can anybody help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it like that, you can encapsulate everything in the script like so:

```
 res.writeHead(301,  "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
  "<html lang='en' dir='ltr'>" +
  "<head>" +
     "<met charset='utf-8'>" +
      "<title>Hola Mundo</title>" +
    "</head>" +
   "<body>" +
     "<script type='text/javascript'>document.onreadystatechange=function(){alert('DOne')}</script>" +
 "</body>" +  "</html>", { "Location": "http://localhost:8086/uploadform" });
```